# Poner a schedule festivos en java y se refleje en la vista pero sin eventos

Tags: primefaces, color, schedule

pintarle al schedule días festivos que pueden ser calculados o traidos de la base de datos por el controlador en java también podría ser por javascript y con un json los paso de java a javascript. Los días festivos no pueden ser eventos porque estos días aunque son especiales tendrán que tener eventos que se les pueda programar.

Pintarle la celda correspondiente al día festivos del schedule, así como lo hace actualmente con la celda correspondiente al día hoy, pero como son muchos días festivos no podría ser manual.

Así como esta en la imagen:

[Imagen de calendario como debe quedar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA3vT.jpg)

Este es parte de mi código correspondiente a la vista  .xhtml

```
<p:schedule style="cursor:pointer;width:60%;height:80%" tooltip="true" 
 aspectRatio="2.2" id="schedule" draggable="false" resizable="false" 
 value="#{SupernumerariosView.lazyEventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule" 
  timeZone="GMT-5" locale="es" />
```

y este es parte de mi código correspondiente al controlador SupernumerariosView.java que ejecuta cuando se pinta la vista

```
 @PostConstruct
 public void init() { 
    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
    lazyEventModel = new LazyScheduleModel() {
    @Override
    public void loadEvents(Date start, Date end) {
        List<Object[]> dataProgramado = tRequerimientoSupernFacadeLocal.findProgramacionBySupernumerario("1313",start,end);
        for (Object[] tRequerimientoSupern : dataProgramado) {
            evento = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
            evento.setId(tRequerimientoSupern[0].toString());                  
            evento.setTitle(tRequerimientoSupern[31].toString());                 
            evento.setStartDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(tRequerimientoSupern[5].toString()));
            evento.setEndDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(tRequerimientoSupern[6].toString()));
            evento.setDescription(tRequerimientoSupern[14].toString());

            switch (tRequerimientoSupern[15].toString()) {
                case "1":
                    evento.setStyleClass("PorAsignar");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    evento.setStyleClass("Asignado");
                    break;
                case "3" :
                    evento.setStyleClass("Ejecucion");
                    break;
                case "4" :
                    evento.setStyleClass("Ejecutado");
                    break;
                case "5" :
                    evento.setStyleClass("Cancelado");
                    break;
                case "6" :
                    evento.setStyleClass("Novedad");
                    break;
            }
            addEvent(evento);

        }
    }
  };
}
```